# Callback from sunburst chart. DASH PLOTLY

Tags: python, plotly-dash

i'm writing a code with a sunburst chart that will present all classes from some type of data, and when the user click on what class he wanna see my dropdown menu should present values only from that classe.

So, my difficult where how to do this callback, cause all the ways that i tried failed.

my df used look like this

```
df = {'Nome': ['Aberdeen Multi Asset Growth Advisory FIM IE',
'Absolute Alpha Global Advisory FIC FIM',
'Absolute Alpha Marb Advisory FIC FIM',
'Absolute Hedge FIC FIM',
'Claritas Hedge Advisory FIC FIM Longo Prazo',
'MOS Institucional FIA',
'Occam Long Biased Advisory FIC FIM',
'Sharp Equity Value Advisory FIC FIA',
'Vinland Macro Advisory FIC FIM'],

'tipo':['Internacional Multimercado Hedgeado',
'Multiestratégia',
'Internacional Multimercado Hedgeado',
'Macro Média Vol',
'Macro Média Vol',
'Renda Variável Long Only',
'Renda Variável Long Biased',
'Renda Variável Long Only',
'Macro Média Vol',
],


'retorno 1 mês':[ '0,79%',
'0,38%',
'0,40%',
'0,38%',
'0,82%',
'4,11%',
'4,02%',
'4,55%',
'0,72%'],

'classes' :
[
'Internacional Multimercado Hedgeado',
'Multiestratégia',
'Macro Média Vol',
'Renda Variável Long Only',
'Renda Variável Long Biased',
'Macro Alta Vol',
'Quantitativo',
'Long Short Direcional',
'Long Short Neutro'],

'número de fundos':
['8',
'6',
'10',
'59',
'37',
'30',
'10',
'15',
'11'
]



}

df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

```
app = Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets= [dbc.themes.DARKLY])


app.layout = dbc.Container(

    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col([
#First Div, where objective of dashboard be presented
#This piece also include our logo on left side
#Few personalization options, simple template
            html.Div([
                html.Img(id='logo_png', src=app.get_asset_url("logo.png"), height= 50
                ),               
                html.H5("Os fundos que acompanhamos estão dividos nas seguintes abaixo"
                ),
#Phrase below our pie chart
            html.P('Selecione a classe que deseja obter mais informações'
            ),
#Pie chart id created inside this .Div
            html.Div([                 
                    dcc.Graph(id = 'pie_class_chart', figure = {},
                    style={'width': '100%', 'display': 'inline-block', 'vertical-align': 'right', })                
            ]),
        dbc.Col(
            html.Div([
                dash_table.DataTable(
                    id = 'tabela-dash',
                    columns = [{"id": i, "name": i} for i in dff.columns],
                    data= dff.to_dict('records'),
                    style_table={'height': '510px', 'overflowY': 'auto', 'display': 'inline-block', 'vertical-align':'left', 'float': 'left'},
                    style_data={
                    'color': 'black',
                  'backgroundColor': 'white'},
                  page_size= 15
                )
            ]),
        ),
#Dropdown of funds classification
#Dropdown-value is the id necessary to insert possible values inside what we want
#  
            html.Div(id="fund_class_selector", children=[                
                html.P('Selecione abaixo o fundo para o qual deseja obter mais informações'
                ),       
                dcc.Dropdown(df['Nome'].unique(), id= 'dropdown-value')],                
                ) 
            ]),
#Options of windowns, with click buttons                      
        ]),        
     ]),
)

####INTERACTIVE FUNCTIONS ARE BELOW######

######

#Callback of first chart

@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='pie_class_chart', component_property= 'figure'),    
    Input(component_id='tabela-dash', component_property='data'))        

def update_graph(fund_class):
    fig = px.pie(df, values = 'número de fundos', names = 'tipo', title = 'Teste' )
    return fig

  


#callback of datatable values
@app.callback(
    Output(component_id="dropdown-value", component_property='options'),
    Input(component_id = 'pie_class_chart', component_property='clickData'))


def display_click_data(clickData):
    try:
        value = clickData['points'][0]['label']
        dcc.Dropdown(dff[dff['type'] == value]['type'])
        return dcc.Dropdown

    except:
        print('error')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, use_reloader=False )
```

Comment: Please add `app.layout` to help you.

Comment: original post edited.

Comment: dff is not supported and hard to run your code.

Comment: sorry dont understand. What should i do?

Comment: I asked for the dataframe in your code to add it to the question. I have a question, why do you need the dropdown menu. You want the user clicking on the pie chart and the data in the table filtered accordingly, or something else? Because I did not understand the role of dropdown and why it is empty at the beginning.

Comment: Oh i see.

Exactly. Exactly what you said, i'm storing the values that i want in my dropdown.

its empty because my df without filters would be huge, probably would de useless.

When the user click on 'type 2' in the chart, my dropdown only should return 'Random 2' and 'Random 5'

Comment: Ok, I understand the clicked value in the pie chart has multiple subcategories in the dataframe, and you ask the user to select from the dropdown menu which subcategory you want to appear in the dataframe, right?

Comment: exactly that, i can return what names are, but couldn't put it into my dropdown

Comment: Ok, please try to save my time and use your dummy data that you added to your question. You will discover that it is inapplicable to use this dataframe with your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248805/discussion-between-glvieira-and-hamzah).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use this code below:

**Full example:**

```
import dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash import Dash, html, dcc,dash_table
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

# dff_dict = ..... add here the dictionary 
dff = pd.DataFrame(dff_dict)

app = dash.Dash(__name__)
fig = px.pie(dff, values = 'número de fundos', names = 'tipo', title = 'Teste' )

app.layout = dbc.Container(

    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col([
#First Div, where objective of dashboard be presented
#This piece also include our logo on left side
#Few personalization options, simple template
            html.Div([
                html.Img(id='logo_png', src=app.get_asset_url("logo.png"), height= 50),               
                html.H5("Os fundos que acompanhamos estão dividos nas seguintes abaixo"),
#Phrase below our pie chart

            html.P('Selecione a classe que deseja obter mais informações'),
#Pie chart id created inside this .Div
            
            html.Div([                 
                    dcc.Graph(id = 'pie_class_chart', figure = fig,
                    style={'width': '100%', 'display': 'inline-block', 'vertical-align': 'right', })
                    ]),
        dbc.Col(
            html.Div([
                dash_table.DataTable(
                    id = 'tabela-dash',
                    columns = [{"id": i, "name": i} for i in dff.columns],
                    style_table={'height': '515px', 'overflowY': 'auto', 'display': 'inline-block', 'vertical-align':'left', 'float': 'left'},
                    style_data={
                    'color': 'black',
                  'backgroundColor': 'white'},
                  page_size= 15
                )
            ]),
        ),

            ]),
#Options of windowns, with click buttons                      
        ]),        
     ]),
)

  
#callback of datatable values
@app.callback(
    Output(component_id="tabela-dash", component_property='data'),
    Input(component_id = 'pie_class_chart', component_property='clickData'))

def display_click_data(clickData):
    if clickData != None:
        value = clickData['points'][0]['label']
        return dff[dff['tipo'] == value].to_dict('records')
    return dash.no_update


app.run_server(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

**Output**
[image]

Comment: perfect, that is what i was wanting